# mpirun --wdir: how to specify a different directory for individual node?

Tags: mpi, host

to run a job on several nodes using mpirun, I would do:

```
    mpirun -np 2 -host myHost1,myHost2 -wdir path/to/wdir myProg
```

where -wdir allows to change the directory before executing myProg on the two hosts. But what if the directories are different on individual host? Can I do something like

```
    mpirun -np 2 -host myHost1,myHost2 -wdir path/to/wdir1,path/to/wdir2 myProg
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify multiple executables, flags, etc. by using the colon operator.

For your example, you'd say:

```
mpirun -np 1 -host myHost1 -wdir path/to/wdir1 myProg : -np 1 -host myHost2 -wdir path/to/wdir2 myProg
```

**EDIT:**

This is also a good way to add a debugger if you're trying to use gdb on just one execution. You can do something like:

```
mpiexec -n 1 gdb myapp : -n 7 myapp
```

Comment: Thanks! It works with a non-mpi application, however it didn't with mpi one, looks like it can't pass the message to the other machine (got a network timeout). One machine is mac the other is linux, could it be the a problem?

Comment: That's a separate issue I think. Can you run any application? If they're in the same wdir?

Comment: My machines communicate through unusual ports. I configured my ssh config such as I can do "ssh machine" with no passwd or port specification and the mpirun first steps go through (--preload-files, -wdir, etc.), but after reading the mpirun documentation it looks like the message passing interface cannot deal (yet) with this kind of configuration...but you're right it's a different issue. No need to continue the discussion here.